# iOS App Submission - Credentials Required

Tags: ios, mobile, submission

I don't know if I am missing something but my simple mobile app displays a list of videos and has a link to the platform website where you can register on website itself.
This account has nothing to do with the app. The app requires no credentials. Yet Apple thinks credentials are required.
What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this before, but what I did was to simply write them a proper note of my applications working, the business model and the user-market it will capture. They accepted my note and approved my app.

Similarly you can put details in 'App Store Connect -> Apps -> your app -> App Review Information -> Notes' or in review details notes and send them proper detailed answer regarding your app's requirements.

Good luck with that.